# Research question - avoiding intermediate variable as control in interaction - colonial data

Tags: r, regression, interaction

**Hi, I'm unsure of if I'm avoiding intermediate variable as controls in my interaction model, since the controls are fixed at the same time as the variable I'm adding in my interaction term.**

My model is as follows, :

```
lm(y=ln_GDPpcconstant2010 ~ x=PropertyRightScore * 
   UKorFrance_dummy + econtrans + poltrans, data = data)
```

predicting how CURRENT Property right scores are associated with GDP controlling for economic transformation and political transformation at during colonialism

I have two controls I'm unsure about:

*Econtrans*: is an index over depth of economic transformation in colonial times.
*Poltrans*: index over depth of political transformation in colonial times.

I'm essentially interested in how different the colonial legacy, since France and England treated their colonies differently.

[image: with or without controls]

Some of these differences are reflected in the index, which is why I'm thinking of either cutting the controls out or splitting my data and just looking at either french or English colonies, and then still controlling for depth of transformation. I'm unsure on what my next step should be. Both group score quite similarly on the controls, but I still get statistically significant results from my interaction regression indicating that former France and English colonies indeed do have different effects

**Any insights or thoughts would be very helpful!**